# Making an HTTP POST request swift

Tags: ios, json, http, post, swift

I'm using the following function to make post an [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) request in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) for my application (uploading photo):

```
static func HTTPPostJSON(url: String,
    jsonObj: AnyObject,
    callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json",
        forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let jsonString = JSONStringify(jsonObj)
        let data: NSData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(
            NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        request.HTTPBody = data
        HTTPsendRequest(request, callback)
}
```

jsonStringify:

```
    static func JSONStringify(jsonObj: AnyObject) -> String {
    if((jsonObj as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]) != nil || (jsonObj as? [Array<AnyObject>]) != nil){

        var e: NSError?
        var jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonObj, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(0), error: &e);

        if e != nil {
            println(e);
            return "\(jsonObj)";
        } else {
            return NSString(data: jsonData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        }
    } else {
        return "\(jsonObj)";
    }
}
```

In this case, the callback function receives the parameter "Bad Request", though I don't know why it happened. Is there a better working way to make an HTTP photo post request in JSON?

Comment: What is `jsonObj`? I see it's `AnyObject`, but when it's an image, is it a `UIImage` object? And what does `JSONStringify` do? My guess is it's uploading a "stringified" version of the image instead of the binary data.

Comment: i added the jsonStringify function to the post. do you have any solution for me?